# Can I install PulseEffects (v3.0.6 or newer) to Ubuntu 16.04.3? If yes, how?

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, gstreamer, audio-player

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 (desktop amd64) to my PC and I would need a good compressor & equalizer program, so I decided with PulseEffects, but they wrote in their GitHub wiki this:

> **Debian 9 / Ubuntu 17.04 and older**
>
> Older Debian based distributions ship with older versions of gstreamer. PulseEffects require Gstreamer 1.12 or above to work. Using a newer version of your distribution is the recommended solution.

[(source)](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/wiki/Installation-from-Source#debian-9--ubuntu-1704-and-older)

Can I somehow install the Gstreamer 1.12 and PulseEffects? If yes, how? Or should I install the 17.10?

Thanks!

Comment: you can build it from the source [link](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/9f9b3de1246c0316f2a273c80841cadc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [these instructions](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-equalizer-pulseeffects-linux/).

I haven't tried it myself.

These are the suggested commands:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~yunnxx/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3/+files/pulseeffects_1.313entornosgnulinuxenial-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i pulseeffects_1.313entornosgnulinuxenial-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

When you run the second command, you may see some dependency errors, which should be resolved by running

```
sudo apt install -f
```

After installation, you can run the program from the terminal using

```
pulseeffects
```